# How many times can you "prestige" in CoD:Black Ops?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I have "prestiged" only once. And then realised, that you can do it again, and again, for no additional abilities apart from more fitout slots, and a gucci logo that indicates you're a "bada$$" (or a masochist in my case).

So, how many times can you prestige ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 15 prestige levels in Black Ops. A full list of what you keep and lose can be seen at the [Call of Duty Wikia](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Prestige_Mode#Call_of_Duty:_Black_Ops)

Comment: Thanks for that. So levelling in prestige is like doing a "super-level". If you can "prestige" 15 times, you have done 750 normal levels, as there are 50 levels between each level of "prestige".

Comment: @giulio (1 level + 15 prestiges)*50 = 800

Comment: @Curt.Yes in total. My original calculation was from starting to "prestige".

Comment: @Curt 814, as you have to reach level 51 to Prestige.